# Old Radio RF Transformmers

Tags: rf, transformer, radio

I want to make a TV transmitter (http://electronics-diy.com/electronic_schematic.php?id=851). There is an RF transformer on it (T1:4.5MHz 1F-can-style RF transformer) that I want to find it from old radio circuits. There are a lot of transforms with different colors and different numbers on them, but I don't know which one I must use? What's the meaning of colors and numbers?

[image]

Comment: They could mean anything. It depends on the manufacturer.

Comment: The manufacturer does not exists anymore!

Comment: How can you know that the manufacturer doesn't exist anymore if you don't know know who the manufacturer is?

Comment: The name of manufacturer is typed on the body.

Comment: I don't see any manufacturer name in your picture. This is important information that you should show. If you know the manufacturer, you might be able to decode the markings you do show.

Comment: It is typed around the hole.

Comment: This is getting tedious.  You've been told that the manufacturer name is important, you know it's there, you won't show it in any picture, and won't even tell us what it is.  Screw this.  Now I'm going to undo my upvote and vote to close too.  I'm outta here.

Comment: The manufacturer name is visible (but probably only if you already know who they are). [Sumida](www.sumida.com). They're an established Japanese company and certainly still exist.

Comment: Did you found any datasheet for this component on www.sumida.com? They did not produce this anymore from a long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of the numbers and colors is specific to the manufacturer of each coil.  There is no standard.  If you can find the manufacturer, then maybe you can get datasheets.  Those should tell you what the markings mean for that family of transformers.  Going the other direction is basically impossible unless you get lucky and recognize something.  The markings will be unique within a manufacturer, but there is no guarantee that other manufactures don't use similar markings to mean different things.

No matter what you do, you must first determine what specs you need the transformers in your circuit to have.  You can measure any you find to those specs.  However, unless you value your time at pennies per hour, you're better off buying new trasformers that come with datasheets and have the specs you want.

Comment: Taking the trouble to characterise an IF or filter transformer at a number of slug (tuning) settings will be hard to justify if you put value to your time.  If it is a hobby and you have a mutual inductance meter available you could try and figure it out.  The transformer may not be common in receiver circuits so you may have to strip half a dozen receivers to get a suitable one.  When testing or selecting parts also remember that some of the tins have a capacitor built in (perhaps for a tank circuit) that if not made to be easily disconnected or replaced.